Center Tikz pictures used as tick labels in Pgfplots
I am trying to use Tikz pictures (piecharts) as x-tick labels in a Pgfplots boxplot and while they appear, I cannot get them properly aligned horizontally, in contrast with normal text labels.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newcommand{\piechart}[3]{
    \def\r{5mm}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angleA}{#1*360}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angleB}{#2*360}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angleC}{#3*360}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[green] (0,0) -- (0:\r) arc (0:\angleA:\r) -- cycle;
        \fill[red] (0,0) -- (\angleA:\r) arc (\angleA:\angleA+\angleB:\r) -- cycle;
        \fill[blue] (0,0) -- (\angleA+\angleB:\r) arc (\angleA+\angleB:360:\r) -- cycle;
        % draw bounding box for reference
        \draw (current bounding box.north east) -- (current bounding box.north west) -- (current bounding box.south west) -- (current bounding box.south east) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[t]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                boxplot/draw direction=y,
                xtick={1,2},
                xticklabels={
                    \piechart{0.5}{0.25}{0.25},
                    \piechart{0.0}{0.25}{0.75},
                }
            ]
            \addplot [mark=*, boxplot={average=auto}] 
            table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
                data\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\
            };
            \addplot [mark=*, boxplot={average=auto}]
            table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
                data\\1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\
            };
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}

I know I could add some x-shifts but is there something more "elegant"?

You have several spaces in the piechart. I can not recommend doing this as it nest tikzpictures. It might be done with a path picture or simply drawn afterwards.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newcommand{\piechart}[3]{%
    \def\r{5mm}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angleA}{#1*360}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angleB}{#2*360}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\angleC}{#3*360}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \fill[green] (0,0) -- (0:\r) arc (0:\angleA:\r) -- cycle;
        \fill[red] (0,0) -- (\angleA:\r) arc (\angleA:\angleA+\angleB:\r) -- cycle;
        \fill[blue] (0,0) -- (\angleA+\angleB:\r) arc (\angleA+\angleB:360:\r) -- cycle;
        % draw bounding box for reference
        \draw (current bounding box.north east) -- (current bounding box.north west) -- (current bounding box.south west) -- (current bounding box.south east) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[t]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                boxplot/draw direction=y,
                xtick={1,2},
                xticklabels={
                    \piechart{0.5}{0.25}{0.25},
                    \piechart{0.0}{0.25}{0.75},
                },
               % x tick label style={inner sep=0pt, red, draw},
            ]
            \addplot [mark=*, boxplot={average=auto}] 
            table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
                data\\4\\5\\6\\7\\8\\
            };
            \addplot [mark=*, boxplot={average=auto}]
            table [row sep=\\,y index=0] {
                data\\1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\
            };
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}



Thanks. However, I cannot help but wonder why this is not the default behavior.

What do you mean? If you put spaces, the spaces will be shown. There is no non-default or default behaviour involved.

I mean that I find it quite un-intuitive that just ending a command with a new line (as it is done in every other modern programming language on this planet) results in "putting a space" which significantly alters the result.

The difference is that the “command” is placed where the content is meant to be typeset. -so it unfair to compare it to the general case of an other programming language.
